# Node-Red - Access a Password protected SQLite Database

Tags: javascript, sqlite, node-red

I am using a SQLite database in my node-red application.

For security purposes, the database is password protected.

Is there any way to supply the password to the SQLite node within the Node-Red Flow?

If remove the password from the database then everything works as expected.

Any help here would be appreciated.

[image: Example of node connection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point there is no support for password protected databases in the node-red-node-sqlite node.

Having a quick look at the underlying library that is used ([sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/)) it doesn't look like it supports password protected DBs either, so it's unlikely to be a quick fix, but I'm sure a pull request to add the capability would be looked at favourably.